# Not Getting Profile properties in Code Behind

Tags: vb.net, properties, profile, provider

I am trying to get Profile properties in the code behind. But I am not getting any intellisence  like `Profile.Homephone` or `Profile.CellPhone`. When I try:

```
Dim memberprofile As ProfileBase = HttpContext.Current.Profile
Dim homePhone As String = memberprofile.GetPropertyValue("HomePhone").ToString()
```

I get `Data is Null`. This method or property cannot be called on Null values error. I have data for current user in the profile Table.
I get following results in immediate window

```
?HttpContext.Current.Profile.UserName.ToString
"sub2"
?Profile.DefaultProfile.Properties.Count
2
? HttpContext.Current.Profile("HomePhone")
"" {String}
    String: ""
```

I  am not able to run property values in page load event.
This is my web.config file setting:

```
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"   connectionStringName="Primary" applicationName="MyFmNow.com"
 type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"  />
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="HomePhone" type="String" />
    <add name="CellPhone"  type="String"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: This [weblog](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/04/12/the-differences-in-profile-between-web-application-projects-wap-and-website.aspx) provides some useful information about this issue. I was facing the exact same issue, but the linked site helped me get the difference. But I'm still trying to find out the reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

You will get an error if you call ToString() if data is null;  you can work around that by doing:

```
Dim homePhone As String = CType(memberprofile.GetPropertyValue("HomePhone"), String)
```

Casting will work OK even if the data is null.  Check the backend database; do you see any values in the aspnet_Profile (or similarly named, can't remember exact name) table for that user?

HTH.

Comment: Data is not null. I have home phone and cell phone values in profile table. These are 2 rows from a table. And still I get null. 

UserId PropertyNames PropertyValuesString PropertyValuesBinary LastUpdatedDate
46B78D75-E1DB-494B-93CC-C87BE650A4B8 HomePhone 7633954101 NULL 2010-03-23 19:16:51
46B78D75-E1DB-494B-93CC-C87BE650A4B8 CellPhone 3134548795 NULL 2010-03-23 19:16:51

Comment: I assume the user is logged in too... The guid matches the user who the profile is for also, so ensure that matches up.  Maybe the query is happening too soon, where do you have the code that queries it in?

Comment: I checked, user is logged in an it does give me back userName "sub2".

Comment: When I do ?HttpContext.Current.Profile.UserName.ToString  it gives the name "sub2" but when I type ?profile.    I don't get property HomePhone and CellPhone in immidiate window.

Comment: I've had issues with profile strong typing, and you don't get intellisense outside of the code-behind file, so that isn't an indication of the setup... though what does your config file setup look like too... I don't see it in the original post...

Comment: This is my web.config for provider.  <profile>
   <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"   connectionStringName="Primary" applicationName="MyFmNow.com"
     type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"  />
   </providers>
   <properties>
    <add name="HomePhone" type="String" />
    <add name="CellPhone"  type="String"/>
   </properties>
  </profile>